# Performance difference between OS X and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, performance, haskell

I've written a signal processing program in Haskell. I've developed the program on my MacBook Pro, using OS X. I also own a desktop which runs Windows. Since my desktop has a more powerful CPU and GPU, I wanted to test my program on it to see how much quicker it would process certain signals, but I did not expect the results.

On my MacBook Pro, the program finishes in an average of 0.013s. On my Windows desktop, the program finishes in an average of 0.090s. This was extremely surprising to me and I started doubting the power of my desktop.

I also have Windows installed on my MacBook Pro in bootcamp, so I decided to test the program that way as well. In Windows (bootcamp), the program finishes in an average of 0.109s.

How is this possible. Is it normal for there to be a performance difference between Windows and OS X for Haskell. Am I missing something?

Comment: Windows takes longer to spawn a process than *nix, and your execution times are very short, so you may just be seeing the effect of this difference. Try making your program run for a longer time (e.g. add an outer loop, to make execution time around 1s or more) to see if the times get closer.

Comment: [Here is some guidance on creating an MCVE.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Paul R's guess is likely right. To go beyond it, though, we'll need to see your program.

Comment: And GPU doesn't matter – it's normally not used by programs at all except for graphics (duh). Only with GPGPU libraries like OpenCL can you outsource signal processing etc. to the GPU. In Haskell you can use [accelerate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate) for this. But this is still quite advanced; for simple programs you'll generally keep it to the CPU alone.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's utterly useless to compare _program execution times_ in the range of milliseconds as a measure for number-crunching performance; your results will always be dominated by initialision stuff. Startup time can be important for scripting and testing, but for actual computation-heavy production code it's pretty much completely irrelevant.

Comment: @leftaroundabout What methods of profiling my code would you recommend to profile my code? I'm profiling my code as in _Parallel and Concurrent Haskell_

Comment: @Valerie94: well, if you've not used used e.g. UNIX `time` but GHC's `+RTS -s` option – that is _ok_ to use for simple profiling; just make sure your examples actually do enough work so the result is in fact representative of the _computations_, 1 second a least. However, [`criterion`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) is much better for reliable results.